# Why is "gen_srl16" used in a standard "SRL16E" instantiation?

Tags: verilog, instantiation

I've got this code snip. It's a standard instantiation, but why is `gen_srl16` used? 
I always thought `SRL16E srl16e (...` should be enough.

```
genvar i;

generate
for (i=0;i<WIDTH;i=i+1)
begin : 
    gen_srl16
    SRL16E srl16e(
            .Q(dataout[i]), 
            .A0(a[0]),.A1(a[1]),.A2(a[2]),.A3(a[3]),
            .CE(write),.CLK(clk),.D(datain[i])); // CE -clock enable 
end
endgenerate
```

Answer (score 2):

In this situation `gen_srl16` is just a name of a `generate for-loop`. It has nothing to do with submodule instantiation.

Following Verilog spec ([IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), ch. 27.4):

> Generate blocks in loop generate constructs can be named or unnamed (...) **If the generate block is named, it is a declaration of an array of generate block instances**. The index values in this array are the values assumed by the genvar during elaboration. This can be a sparse array because the genvar values do not have to form a contiguous range of integers. The array is considered to be declared even if the loop generate scheme resulted in no instances of the generate block.

Comment: Thx! Helped me a lot.

Comment: But why should somebody use this "declaration of an array of generate block instances" ?

Comment: Because the declarations within this block can be referenced using hierarchical names other than from within the hierarchy instantiated by the generate block itself. Please check the file I linked to find some practical examples.